# Error Illegal character(0x1) in compile

Tags: c

I am trying to compile c code in  c++ and I get this error!
Illegal character(0x1)، Why this error occurred?

Comment: Its 21st century. Still Borland? Its last release was in 1997-98.

Comment: Need to see the code.

Comment: What's that funny squiggle after `character(0x1)،`? Perhaps it's a copy/pasta error (code or question).

Comment: My money: a paste of UTF8 data contains the offending `'\1'`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: "Perhaps it's a copy/past**a** error" Hmm, ... pasta! :-) I once saw a keyboard after a pasta error ...

Comment: Apart from that error: Never compile C code with a C++ compiler. Why not use a Java compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you have copied the code from the Internet!

Try typing it.

It will improve your coding ability.

Comment: Then paste that code somewhere so that we can see what is happening.

Comment: okay! exactly say what you are doing? how are you compiling the code, downloading the source code, then? I have copy-pasted and also downloaded the code. Both ways it is compiling in a standard c compiler.

Comment: @Popup That I am able to figure out from the link. I am asking what exactly are **you** doing (**not  the code**) on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there really is a funny character in your file, maybe one your editor doesn't render.

Try using a hex dump program to see each byte of the file rather than an editor.  You may find that there's more characters than you realize in your file.

When I started to learn C ( with an old borland in the late 90s ) I wish somebody would have told me this advice: don't use Borland.  Use linux and gcc and you'll have a much better time.  Now this might not be true of everyone, but it does support windows binaries too and sure would have felt better to me when I was just trying to learn ANSI C.